# MongoDB $inc value by 1 and set max

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have a question, I need to increment a field in DB by 1, thats fine i know how to do it, but i need to set max to 5, i mean it like if value in DB is 5, dont update value to 6, i have this code:

```
collectionName.update({
      name: { $in: namesField },
    }, { $inc: { fieldName: 1 } }, { multi: true });
```

i tried this one and many others, but does not work:

```
collectionName.update({
      name: { $in: namesField },
    }, { fieldName: { $lt: 6 }, { $inc: { fieldName: 1 } }, { multi: true });
```

Thank you for every idea

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of finding only relevant documents, i.e. with fieldName smaller than 5, and then update only them, as you tried. But the finding part should be on the first argument, since the `update` syntax expecting `query`, `update`, `options`, as can be seen [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

```
  collectionName.update({
  name: { $in: namesField }, fieldName: { $lt: 5 }}, { $inc: { fieldName: 1   } }, { multi: true });
```